# Reduce size of a stargaze table in latex

Tags: tables, size, resize

I have a huge table, done with stargazer package in R, and I can not reduce its size, in order to fit my latex document. Everything has to be in a single page and I need all the information that is in this table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Prova de Tópicos em Economia do Trabalho}
\author{Mateus de Almeida Maciel \\ IE/UFRJ}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & Log-Salário \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Intercepto & 0.072$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.0004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Idade & $-$0.001$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.00000) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Idade ao quadrado & 0.072$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.005) \\ 
  & \\ 
 1 ano de estudo & 0.124$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 2 anos de estudo & 0.179$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 3 anos de estudo & 0.261$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) \\ 
  & \\ 
 4 anos de estudo & 0.312$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 5 anos de estudo & 0.357$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 6 anos de estudo & 0.399$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 7 anos de estudo & 0.474$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) \\ 
  & \\ 
 8 anos de estudo & 0.491$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.005) \\ 
  & \\ 
 9 anos de estudo & 0.542$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 10 anos de estudo & 0.707$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.003) \\ 
  & \\ 
 11 anos de estudo & 0.959$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.006) \\ 
  & \\ 
 12 anos de estudo & 1.034$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.006) \\ 
  & \\ 
 13 anos de estudo & 1.122$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.006) \\ 
  & \\ 
 14 anos de estudo & 1.455$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 15 anos de estudo & 1.719$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.006) \\ 
  & \\ 
 16 anos de estudo & 2.131$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.008) \\ 
  & \\ 
 17 anos de estudo & 0.431$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.002) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Homem & $-$0.270$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.002) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Posição 2 & $-$0.169$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.002) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Posição 3 & $-$0.344$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Setor 1 & $-$0.030$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Setor 2 & $-$0.055$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Setor 3 & $-$0.027$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Setor 4 & $-$0.079$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Setor 5 & $-$0.232$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Alagos & 0.045$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Amazonas & 0.101$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.019) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Amapá & $-$0.198$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Bahia & $-$0.346$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Ceará & 0.303$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Distrito Federal & 0.024$^{*}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Espírito Santo & 0.077$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Goiás & $-$0.342$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Maranhão & $-$0.003 \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Minas Gerais & 0.070$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Mato Grosso do Sul & 0.218$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Mato Grosso & $-$0.063$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Pará & $-$0.321$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Paraíba & $-$0.252$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Pernambuco & $-$0.503$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Piauí & 0.116$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Paraná & 0.118$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Rio de Janeiro & $-$0.251$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Rio Grande do Norte & 0.134$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Rondônia & 0.145$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.021) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Roraima & 0.129$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Rio Grande do Sul & 0.237$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Santa Catarina & $-$0.225$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Sergipe & 0.312$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  & \\ 
 São Paulo & $-$0.079$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.016) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Tocantins & 4.446$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
  & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 900,000 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.449 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.449 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 13.309 (df = 899946) \\ 
F Statistic & 13,844.440$^{***}$ (df = 53; 899946) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, can you add a full compilable code starting from \documentclass? Thank you very much.

Comment: Unless you significantly change the design of your table  or split it into columns, you will not be able to fit the whole table onto a single q4 sized page while still keeping the contents readable.

Comment: Done, @Sebastiano!

Comment: Very good :-) for your collaboration.

Comment: You can split it if you want, @leandriis.

Comment: What about the margin size? Are you open to changing that as well?

Comment: Can you place the value and its error into one line instead of into two lines? This could reduce the overall  height of the table significantly.

Comment: Yes, @leandriis =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the `geometry` package to decrease the margins and by removing vertical white spaces as wee as shortening headers and allowing lienbreaks in the contents of the first column, you can squeeze the whole table onto a single page, providd your caption is not loger than 1 line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\quad\quad\quad}l@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lc@{}}  
 & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\textit{Dep. var.:}} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-2} 
 & Log-Salário \\ 
\midrule 
 Intercepto & 0.072$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.0004) \\ 
 Idade & $-$0.001$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.00000) \\ 
 Idade ao  & 0.072$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad quadrado & (0.005) \\ 
 1 ano de  & 0.124$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 2 anos de  & 0.179$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 3 anos de  & 0.261$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.003) \\ 
 4 anos de  & 0.312$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 5 anos de  & 0.357$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 6 anos de  & 0.399$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 7 anos de  & 0.474$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.003) \\ 
 8 anos de  & 0.491$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.005) \\ 
 9 anos de  & 0.542$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 10 anos de  & 0.707$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.003) \\ 
 11 anos de  & 0.959$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.006) \\ 
 12 anos de  & 1.034$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.006) \\ 
 13 anos de  & 1.122$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.006) \\ 
 14 anos de  & 1.455$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.004) \\ 
 15 anos de  & 1.719$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.006) \\ 
   16 anos de  & 2.131$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.008) \\ 
  17 anos de  & 0.431$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad estudo & (0.002) \\ 
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\quad\quad\quad}l@{}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lc@{}}  
 & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\textit{Dep. var.:}} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-2} 
 & Log-Salário \\ 
\midrule 
 Homem & $-$0.270$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.002) \\ 
 Posição 2 & $-$0.169$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.002) \\ 
 Posição 3 & $-$0.344$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
 Setor 1 & $-$0.030$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
 Setor 2 & $-$0.055$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
 Setor 3 & $-$0.027$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
 Setor 4 & $-$0.079$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.004) \\ 
 Setor 5 & $-$0.232$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
 Alagos & 0.045$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
 Amazonas & 0.101$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.019) \\ 
 Amapá & $-$0.198$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
 Bahia & $-$0.346$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
 Ceará & 0.303$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
 Distrito  & 0.024$^{*}$ \\ 
 \quad Federal & (0.014) \\ 
 Espírito  & 0.077$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad Santo & (0.014) \\ 
 Goiás & $-$0.342$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
   Maranhão & $-$0.003 \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
  \end{tabular}
  &
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lc@{}}  
 & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\textit{Dep. var.:}} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-2} 
 & Log-Salário \\ 
\midrule 
 Minas  & 0.070$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad Gerais & (0.014) \\ 
 Mato Grosso  & 0.218$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad do Sul & (0.014) \\ 
 Mato Grosso & $-$0.063$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
 Pará & $-$0.321$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
 Paraíba & $-$0.252$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
 Pernambuco & $-$0.503$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
 Piauí & 0.116$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
 Paraná & 0.118$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
 Rio de Janeiro & $-$0.251$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.014) \\ 
 Rio Grande  & 0.134$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad do Norte & (0.015) \\ 
 Rondônia & 0.145$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.021) \\ 
 Roraima & 0.129$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
 Rio Grande  & 0.237$^{***}$ \\ 
 \quad do Sul & (0.014) \\ 
 Santa Catarina & $-$0.225$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 
 Sergipe & 0.312$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.013) \\ 
 São Paulo & $-$0.079$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.016) \\ 
 Tocantins & 4.446$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.015) \\ 

\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}}
                   Observations & 900,000 \\ 
                   R$^{2}$ & 0.449 \\  
                   Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.449 \\ 
                   Residual Std. Error & 13.309 (df = 899946) \\ 
                   F Statistic & 13,844.440$^{***}$ (df = 53; 899946) \\ 
                   \end{tabular}
                   }
                   \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Note:} $^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

If you place value and error in the same row, you can save even more space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\caption{} 
\label{} 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lrl@{}}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Log-Salário} \\ 
\midrule 
 Intercepto & 0.072$^{***}$ & (0.0004) \\  
 Idade & $-$0.001$^{***}$ & (0.00000) \\  
 Idade ao quadrado & 0.072$^{***}$ & (0.005) \\ \addlinespace
 1 ano de estudo & 0.124$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\ 
 2 anos de estudo & 0.179$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\
 3 anos de estudo & 0.261$^{***}$ & (0.003) \\\addlinespace
 4 anos de estudo & 0.312$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\
 5 anos de estudo & 0.357$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\ 
 6 anos de estudo & 0.399$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\ \addlinespace
 7 anos de estudo & 0.474$^{***}$ & (0.003) \\  
 8 anos de estudo & 0.491$^{***}$ & (0.005) \\  
 9 anos de estudo & 0.542$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\\addlinespace
 10 anos de estudo & 0.707$^{***}$  & (0.003) \\ 
 11 anos de estudo & 0.959$^{***}$   & (0.006) \\ 
 12 anos de estudo & 1.034$^{***}$ & (0.006) \\ \addlinespace
 13 anos de estudo & 1.122$^{***}$ & (0.006) \\ 
 14 anos de estudo & 1.455$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\ 
 15 anos de estudo & 1.719$^{***}$ & (0.006) \\\addlinespace
 16 anos de estudo & 2.131$^{***}$ & (0.008) \\ 
 17 anos de estudo & 0.431$^{***}$ & (0.002) \\   
 Homem & $-$0.270$^{***}$ & (0.002) \\  \addlinespace
 Posição 2 & $-$0.169$^{***}$ & (0.002) \\  
 Posição 3 & $-$0.344$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\  
 Setor 1 & $-$0.030$^{***}$   & (0.004) \\ \addlinespace 
 Setor 2 & $-$0.055$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\  
 Setor 3 & $-$0.027$^{***}$  & (0.004) \\  
 Setor 4 & $-$0.079$^{***}$ & (0.004) \\  \addlinespace
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lcc@{}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Log-Salário} \\ 
\midrule 
 Setor 5 & $-$0.232$^{***}$& (0.015) \\ 
 Alagos & 0.045$^{***}$ & (0.014) \\  
 Amazonas & 0.101$^{***}$ & (0.019) \\   \addlinespace
 Amapá & $-$0.198$^{***}$  & (0.013) \\ 
 Bahia & $-$0.346$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\  
 Ceará & 0.303$^{***}$  & (0.015) \\ \addlinespace
 Distrito Federal & 0.024$^{*}$  & (0.014) \\ 
 Espírito Santo & 0.077$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ 
 Goiás & $-$0.342$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ \addlinespace
 Maranhão & $-$0.003  & (0.013) \\ 
 Minas Gerais & 0.070$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ 
 Mato Grosso do Sul & 0.218$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ \addlinespace 
 Mato Grosso & $-$0.063$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ 
 Pará & $-$0.321$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ 
 Paraíba & $-$0.252$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ \addlinespace
 Pernambuco & $-$0.503$^{***}$  & (0.015) \\ 
 Piauí & 0.116$^{***}$  & (0.013) \\ 
 Paraná & 0.118$^{***}$  & (0.013) \\ \addlinespace
 Rio de Janeiro & $-$0.251$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\  
 Rio Grande do Norte & 0.134$^{***}$  & (0.015) \\ 
 Rondônia & 0.145$^{***}$  & (0.021) \\ \addlinespace
 Roraima & 0.129$^{***}$  & (0.013) \\  
 Rio Grande do Sul & 0.237$^{***}$  & (0.014) \\ 
 Santa Catarina & $-$0.225$^{***}$  & (0.015) \\ \addlinespace
 Sergipe & 0.312$^{***}$  & (0.013) \\ 
 São Paulo & $-$0.079$^{***}$  & (0.016) \\ 
 Tocantins & 4.446$^{***}$  & (0.015) \\ 
 \end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}}
                   Observations & 900,000 \\ 
                   R$^{2}$ & 0.449 \\  
                   Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.449 \\ 
                   Residual Std. Error & 13.309 (df = 899946) \\ 
                   F Statistic & 13,844.440$^{***}$ (df = 53; 899946) \\ 
                   \end{tabular}
                   }
                   \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Note:} $^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @leandriis!